# How to change the distance between the elements in a GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview

I want to change the distance between the elements in a `GridView`, I have to do? It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: please show your `xml` file

Comment: i was fix it and correct: <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gvMain"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivNoteBackgroud"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10sp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10sp"
        android:numColumns="2">
    </GridView>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Xml：

```
<GridView
android:horizontalSpacing  
android:verticalSpacing
```